# What are the constituent morphemes in 'preposition'?

Tags: morphology, etymology, grammar, vocabulary, nouns

The word preposition. I am trying to break down a series of words into their constituent morphemes and am having trouble with the word 'preposition'.
I can obviously see that the 'pre-' is a morpheme in itself. However for 'position' it seems to me that there are a few possibilities.
Would it be pos + ition (my first instinct)?
Or posit + ion?
Posi + tion?
Pos + it + ion?

If your instinct tells you one over the others, please explain why? I know that -ition is a suffix, but have read somewhere else that it is made of the affixes -ite and -ion. Are -ite and -ion seperate *morphemes* also then? Or is '-ition' one morpheme? I know that 'pos-' is a morpheme therefore it's just a case of whether to seperate the '-ition'.

Hopefully someone knows the answer to my question and can explain it to me.
Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: I just wanted other peoples' take on it, as the answer I've come up with is pre + pos + ition but I'm pretty sure that's not right.

Comment: It's tricky, because the root is Latin *pōn-*, whose root in perfect forms is *pos-*. After that, *-it-* is the affix for the past participle, and *-ion-* the nominalizing affix (with the *-n-* dropped in nominative singular). BUT the word came into English without these pieces isolated.

Comment: What Stoney says; note that, in *-it-*, the *-i-* is really a theme vowel, and the actual suffix is *-t-*.

Comment: Couldn't you also argue for the Latin equivalent being "positio", which is constituted from pos-i-tio. "Pos" and "i" are as Stoney and Cerberus said; "tio" is the same morpheme as in oratio ("speech"), derived from ora-re. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tio#Latin

Comment: But how far back do you want to go? There are morphemes and then there are morphemes -- some are newer than others. For instance, Latin _pōn-_ is a daughter of PIE [_*apo-_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080626081000/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE21.html), just as English _position_ is a daughter-in-law of Latin _pōn-_.

Comment: In English or Latin? The answer won't necessarily be the same.

Comment: I suspect that, as far as present-day native speakers of English are concerned, there are two morphemes in 'preposition': 'pre-' and 'position'. I don't think anyone would analyse 'position' as being derived from 'pose' or 'posit' although it undoubtedly has an etymological relationship with those words.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of “constituent morphemes” is very problematic in the case of loan words. A loan word like “preposition” is borrowed as a unit. It is not analysable at a synchronic English level. To analyse it you need to retreat to the level of Latin etymology.

Comment: Wouldn't a synchronic / diachronic analysis yield differing results regardless of etymology? For example, in a native English speaker's lexicon, the word "Kamikaze" is one morpheme, but to a Japanese speaker it's two. (kami-kaze)

Comment: I think that is exactly what I am saying. Or not?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you said. Are you saying that 'preposition' can't be analyzed at a synchronic level? I was saying that 'preposition' can be analyzed at both of these levels. (For example, despite being derived from Latin/Old French, "pre-" is a productive morpheme in English. Both synchronic and diachronic analyses would divide 'preposition' into different constituencies.)

Answer (score -1):

Question 3 Pre-, -posit (something that is posited) -ion.both pre and ion are constituent or bound morphemes while posit is the base or free morpheme

Comment: As others here pointed out, I think the key is that it's a Latin loan word that is not completely analysable in English.